# Apply a filter on a div just using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two columns in bootstrap. A button in one  column opens a menu in the other column and applies a filter over the second column. This is the code.

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 bg-success">
   <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#module" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="module">
     Bring module
   </button>
   <br>
     Some text
   </div>
  
   <div class="col-sm-6 bg-primary">
    <div id="module" class="collapse">
     Some module
   </div>
     <div class="sd">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#module{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

I want to blur the `<div class="sd">` on the expansion of the `#module` div. **WITHOUT USING JS OR JQUERY**

I also want it to look like the `#module` is expanding from the button (not top to down, as is now).

Comment: A sibling selector - something like div:not(.collapsed) ~ div - would help you select the div when its predecessor does not have the collapsed class (remember the . (dot) ). There isn't enough info in your question to answer the second part. Please put up a minimal working snippet so we can see what CSS is being invoked.

Comment: @AHaworth This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nut53zf/)